# The argument type 'MapShapeSource?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MapShapeSource'

Tags: flutter, syncfusion

Im trying to implement syncfusion and display maps with flutter. And I seem to have run into a nullcheck problem right from start (actually the tutorial video). Its the [MapShapeLayer(source: _shapeSource)], that wont work it says:

"The argument type 'MapShapeSource?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MapShapeSource'."

As you can see I have a ? after the MapShapeSource but how I try to fix this it doesn't seem to work, any idées?

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  MapShapeSource? _shapeSource;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _shapeSource = MapShapeSource.network(
        'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bVqXoJvfjC?indent=2');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 50, 0, 0),
        child: SfMaps(
          layers: [MapShapeLayer(source: _shapeSource)],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try declaring `_shapeSource` like `late MapShapeSource _shapeSource;`

Comment: Thank you man. I have to read up on this!

Answer (score 0):

### The error

The message indicates that a nullable _shapeSource is being used somewhere in your code. While adding a `late` modifier is a promise to the compiler that you will be responsible and initialize `_shapeSource` to a non-nullable value before you use it. The Dart team also recommends that you use good programming practice to ensure that you handle the nullable case before using the value. In this case, what happens if you have no access to the network (would `_shapeSource` crash the app?)?

**Here's a couple of examples:**

In the case below the nullable argument dairy is checked for null before it is used with an alternative.

```
// Using null safety:
makeCoffee(String coffee, [String? dairy]) {
  if (dairy != null) {
    print('$coffee with $dairy');
  } else {
    print('Black $coffee');
  }
}
```

In the next case the nullable value is cast as a non-nullable String before being used.

```
// Using null safety:
requireStringNotObject(String definitelyString) {
  print(definitelyString.length);
}

main() {
  Object maybeString = 'it is';
  requireStringNotObject(maybeString as String);
}
```

### Suggestions

In your code you might create an alternative widget to display in the event of network failure or, try casting the value, or provide a null check before using the value with a ternary operator (see example below). This would be a better practice than just adding the late modifier by itself.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 50, 0, 0),
        child: SfMaps(
          layers: [MapShapeLayer(source: (_shapeSource != null) ? _shapeSource : _defaultNonNullSource)],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

You can read up some more on null safety at the [dart.dev](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) website and you can practice what works with your code and get a look at suggestions by pasting the code into [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true) with null safety enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You had used a nullable field for a non-nullable [MapShapeLayer.source](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_maps/latest/maps/MapShapeLayer/source.html) property. You should use a non-nullable field for that. Please check this [documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/maps/getting-started#from-network) to know about loading JSON from the network.